# Vue router keepAlive meta not functioning

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I'm using vue-router, I want to keep a page alive so revisiting will not force refreshing the page.
To achieve this, I've tried add `keepAlive` meta to that page. However, I find that this setting makes no change to router's behaviour.
Here are more details:
I want to keep `PricingView.vue` alive, so my route(lazy-loading) is configured like this:

```js
// router/index.js
const routes = [
  ..., // other pages
  {
    path: '/pricing',
    name: 'pricing',
    meta: {
      keepAlive: true
    },
    component: () => import('../views/PricingView.vue')
  }
]
```

My `PricingView.vue` has an initializing script, which should be executed at initializing:

```js
// PricingView.vue script setup
const init = async () => {
  console.log('initializing pricing view')
  // do some stuff
}
init()
```

My `router-link` is implemented inside a menu component, provided by `naive-ui`:

```js
// NaviComponent.vue script setup
import { h, ref } from 'vue';
import { NIcon, NMenu, NSpace, NLayout, NLayoutSider } from "naive-ui"
import { RouterLink } from 'vue-router';
import {
    HomeOutline as HomeIcon,
    SettingsOutline as ConfigIcon,
    CompassOutline as PricingIcon
} from "@vicons/ionicons5";

function renderIcon(icon) {
    return () => h(NIcon, null, { default: () => h(icon) })
}

const menuOptions = [
    {
        label: () => h(RouterLink, { to: '/' }, { default: ()=>"Home" }),
        key: "home",
        icon: renderIcon(HomeIcon)
    },
    {
        label: () => h(RouterLink, { to: '/config' }, { default: ()=>"Config" }),
        key: "config",
        icon: renderIcon(ConfigIcon)
    },
    {
        label: () => h(RouterLink, { to: '/pricing' }, { default: ()=>"Pricing" }),
        key: "pricing",
        icon: renderIcon(PricingIcon)
    },
]
```

which is nested in layout components provided by `naive-ui`:

```
// NaviComponent.vue template
<NSpace vertical>
    <!-- <NSwitch v-model:value="collapsed" /> -->
    <NLayout has-sider position="absolute">
        <NLayoutSider
            collapse-mode="width"
            :collapsed-width="64"
            :width="160"
            :collapsed="collapsed"
            :native-scrollbar="false"
            show-trigger
            @collapse="collapsed=true"
            @expand="collapsed=false"
        >
            <NMenu 
                v-model:value="activeKey"
                :collapsed="collapsed"
                :collapsed-width="64"
                :collapsed-icon-size="22"
                :options="menuOptions"
            />
        </NLayoutSider>
        <NLayout embedded :native-scrollbar="false">
            <div id="router-view">
                <router-view/>
            </div>
        </NLayout>
    </NLayout>
</NSpace>
```

The truth is that everytime I visit my pricing page, the function `init` is called and I'm able to see `'initializing pricing view'` output to console. My expectation is that the component is lazy loaded for just once, exactly when I first visit it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Assuming that you have read the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive) - is there any reason you're not using the `<keep-alive>` abstract component around the `<router-view />` ?

Comment: I've tried wrapping `<router-view/>` around `<keep-alive>` but it won't work. Possibly because it's functionality changes in vue3:https://router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/#router-view-keep-alive-and-transition

Comment: You did not mention you're using Vue 3 - but if you follow the link that you posted you will achieve the desired effect. You may even update the post with your most recent code.